# How to convert perl object into json string

Tags: json, string, perl, object

I tried lot of time to convert perl object into JSON String. But still i couldn't found. i used JSYNC. But i saw it has some issues. then i use JSON module in perl.
This is my code.

```
my $accountData = AccountsData ->new();
$accountData->userAccountsDetail(@userAccData);
$accountData->creditCardDetail(@userCrData);
my $json = to_json($accountData,{allow_blessed=>1,convert_blessed=>1});
print $json."\n";
```

When i run the code it prints `null`.Is there any mistake i have done ?

Comment: Please check module JSON::XS or JSON in www.cpan.org

Answer (score 8):

First version:

```
use JSON::XS;
use Data::Structure::Util qw/unbless/;


sub serialize {
  my $obj = shift;
  my $class = ref $obj;
  unbless $obj;
  my $rslt = encode_json($obj);
  bless $obj, $class;
  return $rslt;
}

sub deserialize {
  my ($json, $class) = @_;
  my $obj = decode_json($json);
  return bless($obj, $class);
}
```

Second version:

```
package SerializablePoint;

use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Point';

sub TO_JSON {
  return { %{ shift() } };
}

1;

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;
use SerializablePoint;
use JSON::XS;

my $point = SerializablePoint->new(10, 20);

my $json = JSON::XS->new->convert_blessed->encode($point);
print "$json\n";
print "point: x = ".$point->get_x().", y = ".$point->get_y()."\n";
```

Comment: It is generally better to use `JSON` rather then `JSON::XS` directly. It will use `JSON::XS` if available and then fallback to a pure Perl version.

Comment: Thank you very much. I used JSON::XS and sort out my issue.

Comment: For a "pretty" output: `use JSON  qw(encode_json)` (instead of JSON::XS) and then: `sub serialize { my $json = JSON->new->utf8; ... my $rslt = $json->pretty->encode($obj); ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm#convert_blessed), your object must provide a `TO_JSON` method, which `to_json` will then use. It also seems to imply that you could call `JSON -convert_blessed_universally;` before conversion if you wanted to avoid providing your own `TO_JSON` method, though the docs note that that's an experimental feature.